# Use chains in Laravel jobs

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-8, chain

I try to sheduling jobs with chains in Laravel 8. This variant work fine

```
$schedule->job((new  $mainclassname ($parser) )->chain($jobs))->dailyAt('8:33');
```

But if i try to use Bus

```
 $schedule->job(Bus::chain($jobs))->dailyAt('8:33');
```

I get error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain::__invoke() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain::__invoke() at /var/www/cruiz.laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36)